# discord bot that continues to delete a user's message when a command is executed

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

as the title suggests, I'm trying to make my bot keep deleting a message from a user when the command #start is executed. This is my code so far:

```
if message.content.startswith("#start"):            
  delete = True

while delete == True:
  await bot.delete_message(message)
```

but it comes up with an error message saying:

```
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Message
```

Comment: After you delete the message, it's deleted.  What would it mean to delete a deleted message?

Comment: deep man, real deep. Anyhow what i'm trying to make it do is keep a user from messaging when "delete == True". So for an example, after i type in #start, the program will delete that message and any other i message i send. Unfortunately all this current one does is delete the #start and throw up an error